# How do I replace or fix this electronic chip?

Tags: pcb, resistors, repair, replacement

I have a device that runs on a 3.8V Li ion battery.
A few days ago it stopped working.
I screwed it open, took out the battery, and could identify this seemingly fried (?) resistor on the PCB:

[image: side 1]
[image: side 2]

Am I correct in stating that R8 (R6?)  has been fried?

Is there any way I can fix this PCB without any soldering or other equipment?

In case of no, how can I find out what this is and how to order a replacement if at all possible?

**UPDATE:** This is a [Welch Allyn battery handle](https://www.welchallyn.com/en/products/categories/physical-exam/power-handles/3-5-v-lithium-ion-rechargeable-handle.html) component. The chip's gold plate is connected to a push-in metal button like thing that the charger locks into and pushes a high voltage into (~9V). I can't seem to find any spec sheets on the circuitry itself though.

The big metal connectors on the bottom picture (top and bottom) should output the battery's voltage (I checked with a second one of these I have laying around). On this one though, only one side has the proper voltage (when compared to the battery's + pole, which is connected to the metal patch on the right of the bottom photograph.

Comment: Can you give a datasheet or specifications of the chip?

Comment: There are any number of reasons that a resistor fails that is due to another cause, like bad battery cell or ic, and replacing it will do nothing,  additionally there is likely nothing wrong with R6 based on appearance it is just residue

Comment: Clean it with isopropyl alcohol or lacquer thinner and a cotton swab.

Comment: what is this device? context can often be illuminating

Comment: Ocanath: I added the information I have about the device.

Comment: There appear to me to be a few poor solder joints, particularlu RV1 and RV2 - the solder has not "wetted" the component terminals.  The solder should flow smoothly between pad and component terminal.

Comment: @Ocanath, it is a handle for the gizmo that doctors use to look into your ear canal ... it contains a power supply

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like a *burned* resistor to me. Looks more like residue from a poorly cleaned board. Generally speaking, a fried resistor is a symptom of something else failing and not the root cause (although again, I suspect this is not what happened here). You could try reflowing it (get some soldering flux and a reflow iron or soldering iron and clean up that area) or at minimum using isopropyl alcohol + toothbrush to scrub that area and rinse it with water to clean the residue off and verify that the resistor is soldered properly.

Another quick+easy debugging step is to use the thumb test. Power it on and check for hotspots on the board; if one (or more) of the components on that board heats up considerably, it's fried and you'll need to replace them. You shouldn't do this with a battery, but with a current limited power supply (with a fairly low current setting, to avoid risking damage to the PCB).